Python Polars Library Error in a Kaggle Notebook
I have a simple code that uses polars plot to generate a simple line chart using one of the data sets from Kaggle. I had similar code work just fine using pandas but the polars version always gives me an error for hvplot dependency.
I have tried using pip install hvplot, which ensures I am meeting the version requirement >=0.9.1.
!pip install hvplot

import polars as pl

polars_etf_prices = pl.read_csv(source = '/kaggle/input/mutual-funds-and-etfs/ETF prices.csv', has_header = True)
polars_etf_prices.plot.line(x = 'price_date', y = 'open')

In a Kaggle Notebook, I am using one of the available datasets to analyze data using Polars package. Every time I try to run the notebook cell with lines above I get an error for hvplot package.
How can approach this issue?

What is the error you are getting?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For me, running the following in a fresh kaggle notebook (with the mutual-funds-and-etfs dataset attached) works fine.
Installation and imports.
# This is currently needed as there is a duplicate aiohttp installation
# in the Kaggle docker, which breaks pip installs
!rm -rf /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp-3.9.1.dist-info

!pip install -U hvplot==0.9.1
!pip install -U polars

import polars as pl
import hvplot

print(f"polars: {pl.__version__}")
print(f"hvplot: {hvplot.__version__}")

Output.
polars: 0.20.31
hvplot: 0.9.1

Plotting.
df_etf = pl.read_csv('/kaggle/input/mutual-funds-and-etfs/ETF prices.csv')
df_etf.filter(pl.col("fund_symbol") == "AAA").plot.line(x ='price_date', y='open')

Output.

